# RabbitMQ - Elasticsearch consumer

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash

I have a RabbitMQ docker container that runs perfectly and receives messages, storing them inside a queue. What I'm trying to do now is move those messages and insert them in elasticsearch. Now I've spent some time reading about it and according to the elastic documentation this can be achieved by running an instance of logstash and configuring it using the RabbitMQ plug-in.

So my questions are:

1. Can logstash actually play the role of a consumer and get the messages from a queue and insert them in  elastic at all?
2. Assuming that this is the case, and having a logstash docker container is the following correct?

Command to run the docker logstash container:

- `docker run --rm -it -v ~/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/ docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.8.0` - In this situation I'm pointing the container to use a config file outside of the container located on the server here: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/ - took that command from elastic documents.
- Is the following example config file actually correct? bear in mind that elastic, kibana and logstash are basically on the same server running in separate containers.

```
     input {
       rabbitmq {
         host => "IP OF RABBITMQ"; - located on another VM.
         durable => true
         password => "guest"
         user => "guest"
         exchange => "RLMF"
         exchange_type => "topic"
         queue => "db.rlmf"
       }
     }
     
     output {
       elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
     }
```